# PHP Mysql submit form

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i am trying to submit data from a html form using php to a sql database.
It completed up to part 5 but doesn't appear to be any actual data in any of the table rows apart from the auto increment userID. Also is this code protected from SQL Injection?
Also what is the best way to input a datestamp into the SQL database? for example a ClientSince field.

Here is my clientsubmit.php

```
<?php
// Create connection
echo "Made it! Part 1";
$con=mysqli_connect("xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx");
echo "Made it! Part 2";
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
$txtNam = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["name"]);
$txtEmail = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["email"]);
$txtSlots = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["slotcount"]);
$txtSecurity = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["passcode"]);
echo "Made it! Part 3";
$sql = "INSERT INTO accounts (name, email, slotCount, securityCode)     Values('$txtNam','$txtEmail','$txtSlots','$txtSecurity')";
echo "Made it! Part 4";
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }


echo "Made it! Part 5";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

And here is my form:

```
<form name="form" class="form" action="clientsubmit.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="sum2" readonly hidden="true" onChange="updatesum()"     value="1.5"/><br>
Ingame Name: <input type="text" name="name" class="txtbox" /><br><br>
Email Address: <input type="text" name="email" class="txtbox" /><br><br>
Passcode: <input type="text" name="passcode" class="txtbox2" /><br><br>
Slot Count:  <input type="text" name="slotcount" onChange="updatesum()" class="txtbox2"     value="10"/><br><br>
Per Month:  <input name="sum" readonly class="txtboxtotal" style="border: 0px;"     value="15"> Million<br><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Added these:

```
echo "Made it here! 3 ";
echo "   ";
echo $txtNam;
echo "   ";
echo $txtEmail;
echo "   ";
echo $txtSlots;
echo "   ";
echo $txtSecurity;
echo "   ";
```

and it appears that the variables are not holding any data before submitted to the database.

Got it working with the help of you guys, here is the finished code:

```
<?php
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("xxxx","xxxx","xxxx","xxxx");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  die();
  }
$txtNam = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["name"]);
$txtEmail = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["email"]);
$txtSlots = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["slotcount"]);
$txtSecurity = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["passcode"]);
$sql = "INSERT INTO accounts (name, email, slotCount, securityCode)     Values('$txtNam','$txtEmail','$txtSlots','$txtSecurity')";
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: try echoing the "$sql" variable just before executing the query (Part 4), to make sure the query is as required and does contain the desired values.

Comment: Hi sumitb, thanks i just added that but it does appear that the variables are getting no values. "echo $txtNam;"

Comment: can you please copy paste the output of your clientsubmit.php page. You should add a `die()` in the if statement of checking the connection instead of just `echo` because if in future you are not able to connect to database then also your script will continue after completing the `if` block.Remember that `mysql_real_escape_string()` function uses connection variable internally, and if the connection variable is not proper then it will return null.... Also try removing the mysql_real_escape_string function once...

Comment: Hi sumitb, i removed the real_escape parts and it appears they are now getting values, but this leaves my script open to SQL injection, so what would be recommended to do now? Also i added the die(); to the if statement

Comment: Also here is the output "Made it here! 1 Made it here! 2 Made it here! 3 TESTNAME TEST@EMAIL.COM 224 2324 Made it here! 4 Made it here! 5"

Comment: Ah. if its working without the `mysql_real_escap_string()` then probably there is something wrong with your connection object, which version of PHP are you using??? Also you are using `mysqli_connect` for connection..so you can only use 'mysqli_real_escape_string` function.. its syntax is different; it will take connection object as an argument too, beside the string...try to change that and report if still not working..

Comment: Hi sumitb, i am using PHP Version 5.3.10. Also in another part of this thread someone asked me to change the mysql_real_escap_string too mysqli, and that wasn't working. So i'll retest it with and without the 'i' and see if it works just to double check.

Comment: Hi sumitb, Thank for the help it appears to be working now, i'll update the Original Post to reflect the updated code, can you please confirm that it is SQL Injection proof? Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you are using `mysql_real_escape_string()`  and using `mysqli_*()`

change `mysql_real_escape_string()` to `mysqli_real_escape_string()`

```
$txtNam = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["name"]);
$txtEmail =  mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST["email"]);
$txtSlots = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST["slotcount"]);
$txtSecurity = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST["passcode"]);
```

Comment: Thanks! I changed them all to mysqli, but thanks to user sumitb we have found out that the variables $txtNam ect ect does not appear to collect data from the form post

Comment: Or better yet, use prepared statements

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned above `submit.php` and you post form at `clientsubmit.php`.

Comment: he also mentioned that code inserts new row without data, so tha would not be possible with wrong file submited.

Comment: He Write that `doesn't appear to be any actual data in any of the table rows apart from the auto increment userID`

Comment: Sorry should of mentioned the "submit.php" is "clientsubmit.php" just a typo on posting this thread, just edited to reflect what it is. sorry